# Spring Boot: How to include a configuration class that is not in my base package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

I've got a fairly standard spring boot app which is built with gradle from several gradle modules. Here's the directory layout:

```
 - root
   - serviceA
     - src/main/java
       - org.example.serviceA
         - ServiceAApplication.java
   - serviceB
   - serviceC
   - common
     - src/main/java
       - org.example.common
         - CommonSecurityConfiguration.java
```

What I would like to do is to **include** the `CommonSecurityConfiguration` class from the shared `common` module in `serviceA`. Note that `ServiceAApplication` and `CommonSecurityConfiguration` reside in **different base packages**.

I tried to use `@Import(CommonSecurityConfiguration.class)` on my `ServiceAApplication`, but that had no observable effect at all.

The only thing which worked was to annotate `ServiceAApplication` like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication(basePackages = { "org.example.serviceA", "org.example.common"})
public class ServiceAApplication { ... }
```

This approach works, but seems very **coarse grained** to me - it will import each and every component and configuration it finds in `org.example.common`.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I include individual classes into the component scan by listing them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 
@Import(CommonSecurityConfiguration.class) above configuration class. So it would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(CommonSecurityConfiguration.class)
public class ServiceAConfiguration { ... }
```

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it had absolutely no observable effect. Could it be that `@Import` only works when component scans are disabled?

Comment: I am sure it works with component scan. How do you check if it works?

Comment: I put breakpoints in each `@Bean` method and in the `@PostConstruct` method, none of them were reached on application startup. The beans defined in the configuration were unavailable to the rest of the application. If it is supposed to work that way, perhaps I ran into a bug in spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `@CompnentScan("com.example")`, this will tell Spring to look at all the files under the specified path recursively. (In this case it would be `@ComponentScan("root")`)

You find more info here: [baeldun.com/spring-component-scanning](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works; but as I said in the question, this is very coarse-grained. You'll just import *everything*, whether you want to or not. I'm looking for a solution that imports individual classes in addition to those located in my service root package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to control which components are brought in , we can make an annotation , let's call that annotation PickyComponentImport

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface PickyComponentImport{

}
```

Then on our SpringBootApplication annotation we can add a new filter which looks for this annotation.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example.serviceA",
        "org.example.common" }, includeFilters = @Filter(PickyComponentImport.class))
public class ServiceAApplication { ... }
```

Then we can just add that annotation on any class we want included

```
@Configuration
@PickyComponentImport
public class CommonSecurityConfiguration {

}
```

EDIT: I think if you go with this approach you can just componentScan basepackage as root.

Comment: Nice idea, but keep in mind that the `@Filter` applies to *all* base packages, including the package of my service itself. That would mean I would have to annotate all of my own configurations and components as `@PickyComponentImport` as well, or they would be filtered out.